# Show total rep in hint when hovering over the user in /user

Tags: feature-request

Quite often I go to the new Users page (great change, btw) to swap between Week and Month just to see how things are going.  I see some users I may or may not recognize, and hover over their card, hoping to see some more info like total rep or badge summary.  This would give context of the user's overall rep vs current activity.

It would be nice to see the total rep when hovering over the user link, and doubly nice to also see the badge summary next to it. I have an aversion to popups, so keeping with normal hints, maybe something simple like

```
287k | 55 G 1026 S 2086 B
```

Comment: +1, not only would this be very helpful (had the same issue yesterday), it also seems almost like a bug that there is hardly any "info on hovering" in `/user`.